# Theme hospital end

Tags: theme-hospital

I played theme hospital many times, but I have never have the opportunity to finish the game to the end.

What appens when you finish all the levels?

Comment: Oh man, this used to be one of my favorite games. I never finished it either.

Comment: Dammit. This is going to be one of those "everytime you mention it, someone will re-install it" moments...I got the 4th level from the end. Time to dig the disks out.

Comment: Did you see that: http://www.gog.com/gamecard/theme_hospital

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You get your hospital ratings as usual, then there is a VERY short movie of your doctor being photographed with a cup. At last, credits roll down over a static image.

Not a very rewarding ending.

You can view the [Theme Hospital ending movie](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8MHmKQIHl0Q) on Youtube.

Comment: OMG! just that short!!